# error al retornar una lista generica linq

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

tengo el siguiente problema, al retornar una lista genera en un metodo para un viewbag me lanza un error al momento del return, les coloco la imagen para que vean donde me lanza el error

```
    public List<Card> GetCard()
    {
        var user = db.Usuarios.Where(u => u.Email == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        var card = (from Cards in db.Cards.Where(u => u.Id_Usuario == user.Id_Usuario)
                    select new Card
                    {
                        CardNumber = Cards.CardNumber.Replace((Cards.CardNumber.Substring(1 - 1, 12)), "************"),
                        IdCard = Cards.IdCard,
                    }).ToList();

        card.Add(new Card
        {
            IdCard = 0,
            CardNumber = "[Seleccione una tarjeta...]",
        });

        return card.OrderBy(a => a.CardNumber).ToList();
    }
```

este es el error que me esta indicando es este

```
SisVentaOnlinne.Models.Card' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

ayuda

Comment: En el select estas creando una lista de objetos de una clase anónima, tienes que especificar que sean de tipo Card

Comment: deberías retornar 'Card'  como tal y lo que estas haciendo es retonar solo dos atributos  que forman un objeto anónimo  por eso el error, lo solucionas haciendo un  ''select card"

Comment: por cierto edita tu pregunta y añade tu código en lugar de imágenes

Comment: edite la pregunta con mi codigo @Xique

Comment: agregue una respuesta  @Ing.JoseValera revisa si te funciona

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera  si mi respuesta te ayudo deberías considerar marcarla como aceptada de lo contrario dinos en que podemos ayudar para solucionar tu problema

Comment: @xique me indica este mensaje SisVentaOnlinne.Models.Card' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. cuando intento listar la lista

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos opciones

Si lo que quieres es retornar esos dos atributos en una lista puedes crear una clase  por Ej. CardRetornado

> ```
>     public class CardRetornado
>     {
>         public  string CarNumber { get; set; }
>         public int IdCard { get; set; }
>     }
> ```
>
> y en tu controlador en lugar de retornar `Card`  retornas  `CardRetornado` así:

```
public List<CardRetornado> GetCard()
{
    var Card = (from Cards in db.cards.Where(u => u.id_usuario = User.id_isuario) select new CardRetornado { CarNumber= tucodigo ,IdCard.IdCard }).tolist();
    return Card.OrderBy(a => a.Cardnumer).Tolist();
}
```

O si lo que quieres es retornar todo el objeto `Card`

```
public List<Card> GetCard()
{
    var Card = (from Cards in db.cards.Where(u => u.id_usuario = User.id_isuario) select Cards).tolist();
    return Card.OrderBy(a => a.Cardnumer).Tolist();
}
```